# Scroll down a notepad file using java

Tags: java, scroll, screenshot, awtrobot

I want to scroll down a notepad file in order to capture the screenshots, when i try to capture a screenshot i am only able to capture the visible part, i have tried multiple ways but nothing seems to work. Can anybody suggest a solution for this?
Thanks in advance!!
I'm using the below code

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        String shot = "Screenshot"+com.getUniqueName()+".png";
        Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);
        RenderedImage image = (RenderedImage)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);

        boolean isSuccess = ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(SORA_Constants.shots+shot));

        System.out.println(isSuccess);
```

Comment: Just a side note that explains why javascript should not be in your tags here: http://prntscr.com/7li7nz

Comment: Taking screenshots of Notepad seems silly. Why don't you just read the file?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Notepad Window in focus? I presume it is if you're trying to get screen shots from it.
You could just try clicking down.

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
```